# Determine which hooks are being called

Tags: reactjs

If I have some state setup with `useState`, such as:

```
const [s, setS] = React.useState();
```

and I want to put some sort of logging on the middleware, for instance, to log when each call to `setS` is made, I can do something a bit hacky, like this:

```
const [s, setS_] = React.useState();

const setS = x => {
  console.log('setS called with: ');
  console.log(x);
  setS(x);
}
```

But this gets a little unwieldy with lots of items of state. Is it possible to do this in a way that's avoids repetition, for instance, establishing some hook on `useState`?

If you're wondering why I want to do this in the first place, I have some `dispatchAction`'s that are taking a very long time, and I'd like to try and begin debugging these; it's a little difficult as I have no way to know which actions are taking so long.

Comment: Write a custom hook that wraps and replaces setState?

Comment: @jonrsharpe good thinking, I'll take a look into that, thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `useEffect` which triggers when `s` changes. Not sure if this satisfies all of your requirements as it won't be triggered if `setS` is pass the current state of `s`, (ie. `s = 3` and `setS(3)` is called)

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('s changed to: ', s)
}, [s])
```

Comment: I'm guessing this would need to be rewritten per hook?

Comment: For logging purposes yes. Alternatively if all of your state exists in the same scope (ie. same component) you can add each state to the list of dependencies (`[s]` would become `[s, t, u ,v]`). Also read up a bit on the cleanup nature of `useEffect` it can help a lot with debugging for tracking how things change.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the original `React.useState` function to enable logging, but the main challenge is to figure out *who's calling* and for what piece of state, because there's no info passed to `useState()` except for an optional initial value.

#### How to identify the component / piece of state

One idea is to use [`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) to identify who's calling, but it doesn't work in strict mode (and depending on how you have your build process set up, it might be enabled automatically).

An alternative is to throw, and capture, an error and look at its stacktrace:

```js
let oldUseState = React.useState;
React.useState = function useState() {
    let ctx;
    try { throw new Error(); } catch(err) { ctx = err; }
    let [val,updater] = oldUseState(...arguments);
    return [val, function() {
        console.log(arguments, ctx);
        return updater(...arguments);
    }];
}
```

Whenever the updater function for a piece of state is called, you'll get a stacktrace in the console, with the added bonus that the list of callers is cross-referenced with your code, so you can click to see what invoked the function.